# How to use new contex for each request with scrapy-playwright?

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright-python

Here is how I do but I'm not sure it's creating and using a new context for each new request:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = [...]
    cnt = 0

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,
                                 meta={'playwright': True,
                                       'playwright_context': f'{self.cnt}'})

    def parse(self, response):
        self.cnt += 1
        for res in response.xpath('//div[@id="contenu"]'):
            url = res.xpath('.//h2/a/@href').get()
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,
                                 callback=self.get_content,
                                 meta={'playwright': True,
                                       'playwright_context': f'{self.cnt}'})
```

Is this code doing what I want it to do or is it wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The `self.cnt += 1` should be in the for loop before sending a request so a new context is created with an incremented number after each request sent

```
Class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = [...]
    cnt = 0

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls: 
            self.cnt += 1   # <------ increment the count here
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,
                                 meta={'playwright': True,
                                       'playwright_context': f'{self.cnt}'})

    def parse(self, response):
        for res in response.xpath('//div[@id="contenu"]'):
            url = res.xpath('.//h2/a/@href').get()
            self.cnt += 1    # <------ increment the count here
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,
                                 callback=self.get_content,
                                 meta={'playwright': True,
                                       'playwright_context': f'{self.cnt}'})
```