# How to renew scrapy Session

Tags: python, scrapy

----- EDIT ----
*Rewrote the topic + content based on previous findings*

I am scraping using a proxy service that rotates my ip. In order to obtain a new ip, the connection needs to be closed with my proxy service, and a new one opened with the new request.

For instance, if I go to http://ipinfo.io/ip with Chrome and through my proxy service, refreshing the page will give me the same ip, while closing Chrome and reopening + sending a new request will rotate the ip.

Similarly, sending several `curl` command will provide new ip as the connection is closed.  For instance sending several consecutive `curl -x proxy_adress:proxy_port ipinfo.io/ip` gave me :

```
38.15.135.170
144.168.222.130
45.72.34.109
```

With scrapy now, I don't understand how to forcefuly close/reopen the Session between each requests.

Let's say I am using the following scraper that sends http & curl requests to ipinfo.io/ip (the proxy is setup in the middleware) :

```
class IpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "ip"

use_proxy = True   
http = 0 
curl = 0

def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(
        "http://ipinfo.io/ip", 
        callback=self.parse_ip,
        dont_filter=True
    )
    
    yield scrapy.Request.from_curl(
        "curl ipinfo.io/ip", 
        callback=self.parse_curl_ip,
        dont_filter=True
    )
    
def parse_ip(self, response):
    self.logger.info(f"http {response.body}")
    if self.http < 9:
        self.http += 1
        yield scrapy.Request(
            "http://ipinfo.io/ip", 
            callback=self.parse_ip,
            dont_filter=True
        )

def parse_curl_ip(self, response):
    self.logger.info(f"curl {response.body}")
    if self.curl < 9:
        self.curl += 1
        yield scrapy.Request.from_curl(
            "curl ipinfo.io/ip", 
            callback=self.parse_curl_ip,
            dont_filter=True
        )
```

I would expect a different ip on each requests but I have :

```
2022-09-04 13:07:10 [ip] INFO: curl b'143.137.164.56'
2022-09-04 13:07:10 [ip] INFO: http b'161.0.28.170'
2022-09-04 13:07:10 [ip] INFO: curl b'143.137.164.56'
2022-09-04 13:07:11 [ip] INFO: curl b'143.137.164.56'
2022-09-04 13:07:11 [ip] INFO: http b'161.0.28.170'
2022-09-04 13:07:11 [ip] INFO: http b'161.0.28.170'
2022-09-04 13:07:12 [ip] INFO: curl b'143.137.164.56'
```

This is very similar to the kind of results I would have if I were using `requests.Session` : as Session is persistent, I would need to create a new one (which is not so straightfoward, but I easily doable)

The thing is that it does not look like Scrapy implements `requests.Session`, hence I can't find how to renew the Session.

-------- EDIT --------

After testing @gangabass answer I tried to call several other websites before going back to the ip. While it did not work, it provided some surprising results : I misspell one of the website, ending in a 404 response. But what's surprising is while it killed the http loop, the curl loop which was not modified "recycled" the http context : from that moment, the curl requests provided alternatively the first ip it got, and then the ip from the first http request that went trough...

```
2022-09-04 19:40:28 [ip] INFO: curl b'209.127.104.51'
2022-09-04 19:40:28 [ip] INFO: http b'141.193.20.232'
2022-09-04 19:40:28 [ip] INFO: curl b'209.127.104.51'
2022-09-04 19:40:29 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 http://www.lefigaro.fr>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-09-04 19:40:29 [ip] INFO: curl b'209.127.104.51'
2022-09-04 19:40:29 [ip] INFO: curl b'141.193.20.232'
2022-09-04 19:40:30 [ip] INFO: curl b'209.127.104.51'
```

----- EDIT 2 -----

From the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=cookiejar#std-reqmeta-cookiejar) I understand (wrongly?) that the cookiejar may help.

> There is support for keeping multiple cookie sessions per spider by using the cookiejar Request meta key. By default it uses a single cookie jar (session), but you can pass an identifier to use different ones.

So I tried including in my yield a `meta={'cookiejar': self.http},` in order to create a cookiejar per request, but with no luck.

----- EDIT 3 -----

What looks like a promising way is using https://github.com/ThomasAitken/scrapy-sessions (though not maintained anymore).
This library includes a specific middleware and should extend the scraper with a `.sessions.clear()` method (among other)
Though I guess I do not understand how to use it as I get an error message :

> AttributeError: 'IpSpider' object has no attribute 'sessions'

I guess I should reference it somewhere else than just adding the middleware, but I do not understand how/where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***---- Solution 1 ----***

[scrapy-playwright](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright) offers the ability to ask for a new context from the request. I actually tested it before, but I got messed up by how my middleware was injecting the proxy in the request. What was done was working with the standard request but not with scrapy-playwright (and I did not recognized my own ip...)

The meta should be :

```
meta={
    "playwright": True,
    "playwright_context": "some_unique_new_string",
    "playwright_context_kwargs": {
        "proxy": {
            "server": "http://proxy_ip:proxy_port",
            "username": "user",
            "password": "pass",
        },
    },
},
```

The main drawback of this solution is that I am forced to use playwright. While it's a great tool and offer JS interpretation, it's way heavier than the standard scrapy downloader (I have cases where a page takes a minute to get with playwright and below 5 sec with the normal downloader)

***---- Solution 2 ----***

Second solution is a bit more complex. The way the default downloader open connection is set in `scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11.py`

More specifically, session are managed through the `HTTPConnectionPool` (which itself is from `twisted.web.client`) and is set by default, and without possibility for parametrization, at `persistent = True`

Hence it is possible to create a custom downloader :

1. copy the whole `http11.py`
2. paste it into a `handler.py` (name is for clarity, but you can choose whatever you wish) that you'll put in the same folder as middlewares.py & settings.py
3. change the `HTTP11DownloadHandler` class to some custom name, such as `CustomDownloadHandler`
4. Change `self._pool = HTTPConnectionPool(reactor, persistent=True)` to `self._pool = HTTPConnectionPool(reactor, persistent=False)`
5. reference it into your `DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS` of the `setting.py` file

It should look like:

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "[scraper_name].handler.CustomDownloadHandler",
    "https": "[scraper_name].handler.CustomDownloadHandler",
}
```

There is two main issues here:

1. DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS can only accept one type of handler by method (http, https, ...). If you want to use `playwright` on top of this custom handler, well you can't at least until scrapy does what is suggested [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/5510)
2. Every new request will be sent over a new connection. While it match the expectation for a rotating proxy, it can be problematic if you'd like to maintain the connection for some consecutive requests. I tried to include a specific parameter in meta to call the `close()` method on demand but it does not actually reset the pool of connection (and anyway it would close all connections and not only the current one)

Answer (score 0):

What about empty `meta` for each request:

```
def parse_ip(self, response):
    self.logger.info(f"http {response.body}")
    if self.http < 9:
        self.http += 1
        yield scrapy.Request(
            "http://ipinfo.io/ip", 
            callback=self.parse_ip,
            meta={},
            dont_filter=True
    )
```

Comment: It does not solve the issue. Still the same results. Also, I tried using playwright and create a specific context per requests following this source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73306735/how-to-use-new-contex-for-each-request-with-scrapy-playwright. The context are properly created but the ip does not rotate.